# Windows 8 BSOD and Restart

Tags: windows-8, laptop, bsod, reboot

I have Samsung ATIV book 2 laptop with windows 8. I install a game then laptop was stuck . After I click on the restart button . Now i get a blue screen with a restarting logo. (power off is not working) How can i fix ?

Comment: Restarting screen -                                                http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/0/7/L/-/-/07-windows-8-1-install-restarting.png

Comment: Did you get the game by legal means? Sounds like it could be a virus to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the power button to do a forceful restart. Wait 5 seconds and bring the system back up. I've seen Windows 8 get hung on boot ups and shutdowns randomly.

Comment: Tkanks for ur help, I was solved this by removing the battery